# How to use k8s filedselector to act on gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

The fieldselector in k8s can support [equal and not equal](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-operators), I want to use it with the traversal conditions in the RESTful API, so as to achieve traversal filtering
An example of the way I combine it is as follows:

1. Request

```
// list mebers with level is 1
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:80/api/v1/members?fieldSelector=level=1' -H 'Cookie: jwt=xxx'
```

2. Parse url and access database

```
// parse url
var r metav1.ListOptions
c.ShouldBindQuery(&r)    // c *gin.Context

// access database
selector, _ := fields.ParseSelector(opts.FieldSelector)

if level, found := selector.RequiresExactMatch("level"); found {
    db = db.Where("level = ?", level)
}

db.Where(where).Find(&members)
```

But the above method doesn't seem to work for `not equal` to.

I expect to be able to support the discrimination and use of `inequality` at the same time, as follows

```
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:80/api/v1/member?fieldSelector=level!=1' -H 'Cookie: jwt=xxx'

get level
if equal{
   db = db.Where("level = ?", level)
}if notequal{
   db = db.Where("level != ?", level)
}
```

Ideally, extend fuzzy queries such as

```
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:80/api/v1/member?fieldSelector=name~=York' -H 'Cookie: jwt=xxx'

db = db.Where("level LIKE ?", "%"+name+"%")
```

Right now I've only implemented the first degree, being able to take advantage of `equals`, May I ask how to achieve other, looking forward to your guidance